# Meta: Limitation makes no sense here? "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links". Need to link pictures for concrete comparisons

Tags: laptop, linux, cooling, high-end

[
Edit:
I was *very* sleep-deprived and also new to the site and confused when I posted this question.
(Although I decided against deleting it, as I think it's in general best to err on the side of *not* destroying/hiding even apparently useless historical information.)

**I think in *theory* there's an interesting question to be had in in how/whether you can make meaningful judgements about the relative cooling potential of different laptops from looking at their internals and external vents,**
**but in practice I don't think enough manufacturers actually make the required information available, let alone in a sufficiently consistent way,**
so I ultimately decided to abandon trying to ask...
]

---

---

[There doesn't seem to be a specific meta section for this specific stackexchange, so I *guess* I'm supposed to just post here?]

I just went to post my first question, but got "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links".

Does that limitation really make any sense for this stackexchange?

Like, I needed to ask about laptop ports, cooling, etc,
and I needed to link to *pictures* of them all on different laptops to make it concretely clear what's being compared...
(just like 17 links total).

I thought about how to cut out a bunch, but... I can't really see how to do it without making the question significantly worse.

Comment: All SE sites have a meta - https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/ Personally, I think the limit is too soft. Spammers spend all day every day abusing it. Do you *really* need 17 links to ask about a laptop? BTW, it used to be two - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302390/remove-the-2-link-limit-for-new-users-everywhere

Comment: @Tetsujin It's a question like "I need to decide between two different laptops, and all I really have to go off are pictures of the cooling systems. Do you think you can judge anything significant from them?"

Comment: You can just combine two images together - that gives you 16 images.  Seriously, I am going to ignore any question that has so many photos and probably is going to be a large essay.

Comment: @RohitGupta Mm, I forgot about this question. Maybe I should just delete it... (I was *very* sleep-deprived and also new to the site and confused when I posted it.)
Although in *theory* I think there's an interesting subject in how/whether you can make meaningful judgements about the relative cooling potential of different laptops from looking at their internals,
but in practice I don't think enough manufacturers actually make the required information available, let alone in a sufficiently consistent way.